# New configuration files for the Apache web server were not created due to the errors in configuration templates:

Tags: nginx, php, apache2, plesk

I'm running a pleks server on ubuntu and recently after trying to upgrade my php version, I managed to cause a lot of errors, one being that the site is currently displaying

going to the site page shows the default apache page, no longer the site page.

running `nginx -t` returns a duplicate error

```
nginx -t
nginx: [warn] duplicate value "TLSv1" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf:1
nginx: [warn] duplicate value "TLSv1.1" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf:1
nginx: [warn] duplicate value "TLSv1.2" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf:1
nginx: [emerg] "ssl_prefer_server_ciphers" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf:3
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Hiw can I fix the duplicate error and how can I show my site page again? (my path is directing to an index.php file

Comment: We don't accept questions about Plesk here. See [Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/8094/126632)

Comment: It's a server issue on ubuntu with nginx?

Comment: Yes, and we don't accept the question because it's Plesk. You can find the [complete explanation on meta](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/8055/126632).

Comment: And if I asked the question without mentioning plesk it would have been fine? Because it being plesk isn't really relevant to the issue?

Comment: It is relevant to the issue, because it's Plesk. This is not the place to argue about it.

Comment: It's confusing to me because the issue isn't plesk related but Ubuntu server and nginx/apache. It's really unpleasant because I've asked a question yesterday and it got answered and I've seen plenty of plesk questions on stackExchange. So it's also not consistent at all.